# I have a JavaScript error I do not understand

Tags: javascript

I have an issue in Javascript, I am trying to make a card matching game and I want to use pictures rather than use letters and numbers I saw a seperate post telling me to use a thing called "getimage" and it was used like this

```
var dogs = [
getimage("images/1.png"),
getimage("images/1.png"),
getimage("images/2.png"),
getimage("images/2.png"),
getimage("images/3.png"),
getimage("images/3.png")
];
```

So, the output told me that I used getImage before it was defined and I do not understand why because the reference I was using had not defined it seemed to work (Theirs was for a different purpose)

Can anyone help me with this?

Full code:

```
var Tile = function(x, y, dogs) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.dogs = dogs;
this.width = 70;
};

Tile.prototype.drawFaceDown = function() {
fill(214, 247, 202);
strokeWeight(2);
rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.width, 10);
image(getImage("images/6.png"), this.x, this.y, this.width, this.width);
};

Tile.prototype.drawFaceUp = function() {
fill(214, 247, 202);
strokeWeight(2);
rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.width, 10);
image(this.face, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.width);
};


var dogs = [
getimage("images/1.png"),
getimage("images/1.png"),
getimage("images/2.png"),
getimage("images/2.png"),
getimage("images/3.png"),
getimage("images/3.png")

];
var memory_values = [];
var memory_tile_ids = [];
var tiles_flipped = 0;
Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function(){
var i = this.length, j, temp;
while(--i > 0){
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
    temp = this[j];
    this[j] = this[i];
    this[i] = temp;
 }
}

function newBoard(){
tiles_flipped = 0;
var output = '';
memory_array.memory_tile_shuffle();
for(var i = 0; i < memory_array.length; i++){
    output += '<div id="tile_'+i+'" 
onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\''+memory_array[i]+'\')"></div>';
}
document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = output;
}




function memoryFlipTile(tile,val){
if(tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2){
    tile.style.background = '#FFF';
    tile.innerHTML = val;
    if(memory_values.length == 0){
        memory_values.push(val);
        memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
    } else if(memory_values.length == 1){
        memory_values.push(val);
        memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
        if(memory_values[0] == memory_values[1]){
            tiles_flipped += 2;
            // Clear both arrays
            memory_values = [];
            memory_tile_ids = [];
            // Check to see if the whole board is cleared
            if(tiles_flipped == memory_array.length){
                alert("Yay! You did it!");
                document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
                newBoard();
            }
        } else {
            function flip2Back(){
                // Flip the 2 tiles back over
                var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
                var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
                tile_1.style.background = 'url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat';
                tile_1.innerHTML = "";
                tile_2.style.background = 'url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat';
                tile_2.innerHTML = "";
                // Clear both arrays
                memory_values = [];
                memory_tile_ids = [];
            }
            setTimeout(flip2Back, 700);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The browser doesn't have a built-in function named `getimage`. You could create a function with that name, but you havn't, and so you're trying to access something that doesn't exist. Whatever source you were looking at, see how they implemented it.

Comment: Its better if you can share the link from where you got getimage as I am not aware of any such function

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/memory-game-scoring/5447543729160192    -This is where I got my info I have used this asigned by my teacher before and the stuff has worked but whenever i try this, it does not work.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Rather than storing them directly in an array, couldn't you create an array of objects e.g :
var fruitsArray = [
  { name: 'Banana', image: 'banana.jpg' }, 
  { name: 'Apple', image: 'apple.jpg' }, 
  { name: 'Orange', image: 'orange.jpg' }
];

then call them from there?

like here: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/using-images-in-array-object/219080/3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function called `getimage` that does what you need, or incorporate the plugin or library where that function is created so that you can use it. If you are using a plugin/library, check the documentation to make sure you are using the right syntax when you call `getimage`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your variable names. You're using a combination of lowercase and camelcase (`getImage` vs `getimage`).